# All res.local variables become undefined in error handler

Tags: node.js, express

Situation: Node.js web app using Express

I need the `req` object in my layout pug script so I have:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.req = req;
  // ...
  next();
});
```

I also have the standard error handler:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  res.status(statusCode).render("error");
})
```

The above worked fine for a very long time. But today, I had a `413 request entity too large` error (because the limit in `body-parser` was too low). When this happened, in `error.pug`, all `res.local` variables were undefined.

When the error happened, the code flow did not go through my router middleware. The error handler was invoked from, I presume, somewhere inside Express.

Is this by design? Does it mean that error pug scripts, if they are using `res.local` variables, have to test for the absence of `res.local` variables?

If it is of any help, my error.pug contains something like and it bombed when `req` was `undefined`:

```
a(href='/contact', class=(req.url.startsWith('/contact')) ? 'active' : undefined) Contact
```

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: In error.pug, the `req` object and other `res.local` objects were `undefined`. My pug script was using `req.url` so it bombed.

Comment: can you update your question with your `error.pug` and were you used `bodyParser`

Comment: Thanks for helping. Done.